# How to set conditions/filters on references when using Load* methods

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have two tables: Customer and Orders. The customer has a reference to Orders like such:

```
[Reference]
public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

The Order class has an attribute `Deleted`. I'd like to load all Customers (or a subset), and include the Orders, but not the ones with Deleted=true. Can this be done with LoadSelect methods, or what is the recommended way?

Something that would roughly equal the following SQL:

```
select * from Customers C 
join Orders O on O.CustomerId = C.Id 
where O.Deleted = False
```

Is this the best way?

```
var orderIds = resp.Customers.Select(q => q.Id).ToList();
var allOrders = Db.Select<Order>(o => orderIds.Contains(o.CustomerId) && !o.Deleted);
foreach (var order in allOrders)
{
    var cust = resp.Customers.First(q => q.Id == order.custivityId);
    if (cust.Orders == null) cust.Orders = new List<Order>();
    cust.Orders.Add(order);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added a new `Merge` API [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/b67cf1510bf991065c135098fd4219ebae408d1a) to automatically join a parent collection with their child references that will make this a little easier.

With the new API you can select customers and orders separately and merge the collections together, e.g:

```
//Select only Customers which have valid orders
var customers = db.Select<Customer>(q =>
    q.Join<Order>()
     .Where<Order>(o => o.Deleted == false)
     .SelectDistinct());

//Select valid orders
var orders = db.Select<Order>(o => o.Deleted == false);

customers.Merge(orders); //merge the results together

customers.PrintDump();   //print the results of the merged collection
```

This change is available from **v4.0.39+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).