# How to make a query that returns a dictionary with values from two joined tables in Servicestack.Ormlite?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I've got two tables, Card and User. Card has a reference to user, so that a user can have many cards, but a card can only have one user.
I have made this mysql-query that returns the Card.Id and User.LastName:

```
SELECT Card.Id,User.LastName FROM Card
    left join User on Card.UserId = User.Id
    where Card.Id = '1';
```

How can I make that query with servicestack ormlite?
I've tried something like this:

```
var cardIdAndUserName = db.Dictionary<int, string>(db.From<Card>()
    .LeftJoin<Card, User>((c,u) => c.UserId == u.Id)
    .Select(card => new {card.id, user.Lastname}));
```

I could not get the code above to work because the .Select statement will only let me get columns from the Card table. I guess I could make a db.Select(InfoINeedObject) intead of the db.dictionary call, but then I have to create a new class, InfoINeedObject.

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103559/how-to-set-conditions-filters-on-references-when-using-load-methods/29109309#29109309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are new Select Overloads that allows you to specify multiple tables [added in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/c346a96bbe36913a0f1d1a09c793b80a68b7bf9d) which will now let you do:

```
var cardIdAndUserName = db.Dictionary<int, string>(db.From<Card>()
    .LeftJoin<Card, User>()
    .Select<Card,User>((card,user) => new {card.id, user.Lastname}));
```

> Note: Where joins can be implied [it doesn't need to be specified](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins)

This change is available from **v4.0.39+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).